# Get last Element (<a>) tag content from html

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string with some HTML.  In the HTML is a list of anchors (`<a>` tags) and I would like to get the last of those anchors.

```
<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/suppliers">Suppliers</a>
    <a href="/suppliers/jewellers">This One i needed</a>  
    <span class="currentpage">Amrapali</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why a downvote? At least write a comment.


@user2679838 : Could you clarify your questiona bit about what you're trying to do? That's probably the reason for the downvote.

Comment: i need to get last a tag <a href="/suppliers/jewellers">This One i needed</a> by using preg_match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for the next `a` tags with a negative lookahead:

```
(?s)<a(?!.*<a).+</a>
```

and the code:

```
preg_match("#(?s)<a(?!.*<a).+</a>#", $html, $result);
print_r($result);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="/suppliers/jewellers">This One i needed</a>
)
```

[Regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/uY5aI0) | [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/Vn8jX1)

Answer (score 4):

Make use of [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) Class.

```
<?php
$html='<div id="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/suppliers">Suppliers</a>
    <a href="/suppliers/jewellers">This One i needed</a>
    <span class="currentpage">Amrapali</span>
</div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag) {
   $arr[]=$tag->nodeValue;
}
echo $yourval = array_pop($arr); //"prints" This One i needed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$string = '<div id="breadcrumbs">
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/suppliers">Suppliers</a>
<a href="/suppliers/jewellers">This One i needed</a>  
<span class="currentpage">Amrapali</span>
</div>';


//$matches[0] will have all the <a> tags
preg_match_all("/<a.+>.+<\/a>/i", $string, $matches);


//Now we remove the <a> tags and store the tag content into an array called $result
foreach($matches[0] as $key => $value){

    $find = array("/<a\shref=\".+\">/", "/<\/a>/");
    $replace = array("", "");

    $result[] = preg_replace($find, $replace, $value);
}


//Make the last item in the $result array become the first
$result = array_reverse($result);

$last_item = $result[0];

echo $last_item;


?>
```